# Sylius Symfony The controller for URI "/_profiler/open" is not callable: Environment variable not found: "STRIPE_PUBLIC"

Tags: symfony4, sylius

I'm working with sylius SYMFONY after pulling update from other branch got this error says can't  find environment variable STRIPE_PUBLIC
Where do I find stripe public?

Here's screenshot and code from .env

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_DEBUG=1
APP_SECRET=1i2oAAA8219
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1/store_test
```

file[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution by updating .env and added like this below.

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC=pk_test_51Grc7GJBEkDjTIHsJpHNUymZQYmjg4ZYkzS5CCJblHf2AektBjT60WtER11ezn2zN8WySq333Cv6XwDC8DwFlKla00Nc2NgGYt
```